# Update SP.FieldLink through SharePoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to set a Contenttype's field to be hidden. When I try to do this I get the error:
`The type SP.FieldLink does not support HTTP PATCH method`

I'm able to retrieve the field's information with a GET request to:
`_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/contenttypes('0x0100BC6B4C23BB69EA4CB2BFF27663852DFB')/fieldlinks('de414532-ada6-4d9e-99b3-0a8cfcf9d187')`

But when I try to update the FieldLink with a POST request like this:

```http
POST _api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/contenttypes('0x0100BC6B4C23BB69EA4CB2BFF27663852DFB')/fieldlinks('de414532-ada6-4d9e-99b3-0a8cfcf9d187')
X-RequestDigest: <digest value>
X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
If-Match: *

{"Hidden":true}
```

it returns the error `The type SP.FieldLink does not support HTTP PATCH method`.

Am I missing something or is this really not possible through the REST API?

It can be done through PnP PowerShell (which doesn't use the REST API) like this:

```
$contentType = Get-PnPContentType -List "MyList" -Identity "Item"
$contentType.FieldLinks.GetById("de414532-ada6-4d9e-99b3-0a8cfcf9d187").Hidden = 1
$contentType.Update(0)
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

---

As a bonus, here's a quick and dirty code to test this using PnPJS:

```js
import { sp, spPost } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

const myContentType = sp.web.lists.getByTitle('MyList').contentTypes.getById('0x0100BC6B4C23BB69EA4CB2BFF27663852DFB');

spPost(myContentType.fieldLinks.concat(`('de414532-ada6-4d9e-99b3-0a8cfcf9d187')`, {
    body: JSON.stringify({
        Hidden: true,
    }),
    headers: {
        'If-Match': '*',
        'X-HTTP-Method': 'MERGE',
    }
}),
```

---

### Update

Trying this on `fields` instead of `fieldlinks` gives a different error. My request looks like this:

```http
POST _api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/contenttypes('0x0100BC6B4C23BB69EA4CB2BFF27663852DFB')/fields('de414532-ada6-4d9e-99b3-0a8cfcf9d187')
X-RequestDigest: <digest value>
X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
If-Match: *

{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.FieldLink"}, "Hidden":true}
```

gives the error `Cannot change Hidden attribute for this field`.
Important to note, I'm trying this on a choice field (I know those can be hidden).